# Using column nos as variable value

Tags: shell, variable

I want to use a set of columns depending on some version conditions but when I set

```
String="$39+$41+$43+$45+$47+$49+$51+$53"
```

`echo $String` returns

```
9+1+3+5+7+9+1+3
```

Comment: And where's the question?

Comment: Is the problem that you want the literal string `$39+$41+...` or that you want the sum?

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
String="${39}+${41}+${43}+${45}+${47}+${49}+${51}+${53}"
```

which give

```
set $(seq 101 200)
String="${39}+${41}+${43}+${45}+${47}+${49}+${51}+${53}"
echo $String
139+141+143+145+147+149+151+153
```

edit:

if you want the string, do not use double quote

```
string='$39+$41+$43+$45+$47+$49+$51+$53'

echo $string
'$39+$41+$43+$45+$47+$49+$51+$53'
```

Comment: No i want to use the same string as it is in some other expression the value of String changes in if condition for one condition it is even and for other it is odd(as shown in example)